# Decompress ZLib archive containing directory

Tags: c#, zip, archive, zlib, dotnetzip

I have an archive in the Zlib format. I am trying to decompress it using C#. The archive contains one file and a folder full of more files and folders. So far, I have been able to decompress the single, top-level file. However, the directory hasn't magically appeared and I don't even know where to start with it. So far, I have successfully decompressed the top-level file with DeflateStream. I have DotNetZip and am playing with it but I don't know how to create a folder full of files from a byte array returned by the decompression function found [here](https://github.com/eropple/dotnetzip/blob/master/Examples/C#/ZLIB/ZlibDeflateInflate.cs).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the `ZipArchive` class that comes with .NET 4.5? Post some code and we'll help!

Comment: I hadn't heard of it. However, I tried using the code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3) and got an InvalidDataException with the message `End of Central Directory record could not be found`. Is that class suitable for decompressing ZLib?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "ZLib archive". Do you mean zip? gz? tar.gz?

Comment: If you can convince me of that, it will have significant impact on my project. The file is a proprietary file format that is created in Delphi using the default ZLib compression. It has a ZLib header and skipping the header allows the top-level file to be decompressed using DeflateStream. That's as far as I've gotten. Everything else I try results in an error from the implementation.

Comment: @CoryNelson There is no such thing as "ZipArchive" in .NET 4.5, DeflateStream and GZipStream only.

Comment: @KimSchneider [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @CoryNelson I missed the reference to System.IO.Compression :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
{
   foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
   {
      e.Extract(TargetDirectory, true);  // overwrite existing files
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't even get that to compile. Is that code using the `System.IO.Compression namespace`, `Ionic.ZLib`, or `Ionic.Zip`?

Comment: The ZipFile class is declared in the System.IO.Compression namespace.  It requires the v4.5 of the framework.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx